# Get Forum Files from Vanilla Forum

Tags: php, html, css, xampp, vanilla-forums

I had homework of making a forum about a subject, tomorrow I have show my final work.

I used VANILLA FORUMS to make the webiste, created it, modified what needs to be modified got the themes and everything done, now im looking for someway to import only the website and database files ( html/css/js/php... files ) plus the database, like get all the files that make the website launch without re-opening Xampp everytime

to sum up Is there anyway I can import the webiste files from the XAMMP folder so its shareable ?
Or if somebody knows simply where they must be.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

i believe they could be in Htdocs, but not sure if dragging them would save their state as it is displayed on the Localhost/yourforum

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways and im guessing you need the first one:

1. Make a dump of your database, store that file in your document root. And now zip everything. The other person can unzip it and load the database dump in their database and proceed.
2. You add it to a repository and send the link to the other party. The other party pulls it from the repository, does (something similar to) `composer install` and `npm build` and a form of migration the database.

In either case, it's recommended that you create a `readme.md`, explaining how to set up the project.

Based on the fact that you're asking, I think you're looking for the first solution, which is the most simple and acceptable for entry level programmers/students.

Comment: Appreciate your help so much,

Comment: But im looking to get the Html, CSS, JS files aswell, your ways are about getting the database only ? or i am mistaken

Comment: You are mistaken. The document root is the `/` path of your files. Where your index.php is. Your projects file directory

Comment: forgive my lack of knowledge, but that's my issue i didn't get how to do it, (it's my first year studying computer sciences)

Comment: there is a file on my xampp called Htdocs that contains a file called InterHelp and InterHelp is my Forum name

Comment: i found another file that contains all my database, the database i have no issue with it because i already copied it all on another file, 
but my issue is grabing the files that will make my project launchable on another computer if you get what i mean

Comment: Forgive my dumbness again, im just a beginner at all of this

Comment: It's still as I explained in my post. If you dont know where your document root is, google "xampp document root" and you'll find the files